# find size of text stored in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, size

I wanted to know that how can we find the size of text stored in a specific column.
For example : if the same text would have been stored in a .txt file then we can see its size as 5kb or 10kb or whatever.
My column datatype is `longtext`.

is their any sql query for that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's not a multibyte character set, why not just use the LENGTH() function?

```
create table t
( a longtext );
insert into t (a) values ('abcdef');

select length(a) from t;
```

That should get you the number of characters, or bytes if there are multi-byte characters.

As noted in the comments, use CHAR_LENGTH() for character length of strings in multi-byte character sets.

Comment: This DOES work for multi-byte characters if you want to know how many bytes the string uses. E.g. for three 2-byte characters `LENGTH()` will return 6. If you want character count use `CHAR_LENGTH()`

Answer (score 2):

There's a function to return the number of *characters*, regardless of the number of bytes:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

So, `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(MyField)) FROM MyTable`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is the best for multibyte character set,

```
select CHAR_LENGTH ('abc æøå');
```

will give you 7.

Or

```
select CHAR_LENGTH ('漢語');
```

will give you 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
select length('this is a long text')
```